# Which version of swift compiler is the default Xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have some tests failing on a new machine with Xcode 6.4, with this error:

```
'NSDictionary' is not implicitly convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?
```

On my machine (still on a old Xcode 6.2) the test is ok. Unfortunately I can't upgrade my machine for the moment.

Any suggestion on how can I achieve the same behaviour on both Xcode versions? I'm suspecting different Swift compilers are used, because that part of code isn't changed at all...

**EDIT**: Found the versions:

- Swift version 1.1 (swift-600.0.57.4) -> Xcode 6.2
- Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.53.1 clang-602.0.53) -> Xcode 6.4

Comment: can you share error lines?

Comment: That's the error. `'NSDictionary' is not implicitly convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?`

Comment: Özgür wants to se the line of code that throws the error.

Comment: add your answer as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Move the edit to the answer and  tell how you find that.

Comment: How you find the version, in Terminal:

    `xcrun swift --version`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the versions by running `xcrun swift --version`:

- Swift version 1.1 (swift-600.0.57.4) -> Xcode 6.2
- Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.53.1 clang-602.0.53) -> Xcode 6.4